# Testing a method which calls private void method inside using mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I want to test a method which internally calls a void method.

Below is the code

```
public String process(MKSConnectionParams mksConnectionParam, IProgressMonitor progressMonitor) throws Exception {

    if (null != progressMonitor) {
        progressMonitor.beginTask("Starting the creation of report", 100);
    }
    if (null == mksConnectionParam) {
        initialize(MksLibFactory.getDefault());
    }
    else {
        initialize(mksConnectionParam, MksLibFactory.getDefault());
    }
           --------------
}

public void initialize(MKSConnectionParams mksConnectionParam, IMksLibrary mksLibDefault) throws Exception {
    paramMKSConnectionParams = mksConnectionParam;
    GlobalConstants.hostName = paramMKSConnectionParams.hostname;
    GlobalConstants.port = String.valueOf(paramMKSConnectionParams.port);
    try {
        localISi = mksLibDefault.getSi(paramMKSConnectionParams);
        localIIm = mksLibDefault.getIm(paramMKSConnectionParams);
    }
    catch (MksLibException | AuthenticationError e) {
        throw e;
    }

    ProjectInfo prjInfo = localISi.getProjectInfo(pathToPj);
    projRevCmd = prjInfo.getConfigPath().getConfigPath() + "#b=" + projectRevision;

}
```

I am writing mockito test case for process() method. Testing is getting failed when `initialize(mksConnectionParam, MksLibFactory.getDefault())` is called. It is because in the process we are calling real  mks connection and I am passing dummy user name and password. 
We aren't able to mock this initialize method. Is there any way to do this?

Small pseudocode would be of great help.

Earlier I had initialize method as `private`. Would changing it to `public` make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to test this scenario, and different people would advocate different approaches, mostly based on personal preference.

Notice that testing this, will require changes in the code of the class you're testing (I believe you neglected to mention its name). There is one exception, and that's if you're using PowerMock. I won't go into the details here, but you find out more on how to incorporate it into your mockito code [here](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13).

Back to regular testing methods, the problem is that you're using the real `IMksLibrary` instead of a mock, and that's because you obtain a reference to it inside the `process` method. Here are a few method that you might want to consider:

1. Change the signature of the `process` method to receive the reference to the `IMksLibrary` instance, so that the test code can supply a mock of it
2. Instead of creating the reference inside the `process` method inject a reference to the class, either by using some DI framework (e.g. Spring, Guice, CDI, etc.), or as a constructor parameter
3. Create a protected method called something like `getIMjsLibraryInstance()` in the class, that will return `MksLibFactory.getDefault()`, and use it instead of the explicit code (this is the `Extract Method` refactoring that can be automatically done by most IDEs for Java nowadays). In the test code, you need to create a subclass (this is why it's my least favorite method) which overrides this method and returns a mock, and test the subclass instead of the real class. Notice that this is the **ONLY** method that you should subclass

You might feel deterred from using the third method, since in effect, you're not really testing the class that you meant to test (but rather a subclass of it). I tend to agree that this has a bed smell to it. However, keep in mind, that unlike the other two methods, this will not require any changes to the clients of the class (this is a pretty strong argument in favor of it).

There are other methods that you can use, but they are pretty similar in nature to the first two methods, and they also require some changes in the code.

If you feel that any "regular" method of testing is not good enough (due to code changes or whatever other reason), you are welcomed to take a look at [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/), which will enable you to intercept the static method call that returns the `IMksLibrary` instance, and return a mock instead. A word of caution though. There are some serious coupling that happens when these type of solutions are used, so it is usually not highly recommended, unless you are really in a dire need.